# Why define a macro insted of using directly?(Please see description for what exactly i want)

Tags: c, macros, linux-kernel

I am traversing through linux kernel code. I found a macro defined as `#define __async_inline __always_inline`. I searched for `__always_inline`,I found the following statement `#define __always_inline inline`. My question is why they need to do like this? They can directly use `inline` instead of this macro's?

Comment: apparently `inline` is standard only from the `C99` version of the language, I assume they have done this to avoid hardcoding the keyword inside the codebase.

Comment: May be in future, they may add more functionality/property to the macro and also sometimes for portability issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common way to parameterize code, to move a decision of some sort (in this case, the use of `inline`) to a single place, so that should that decision change (for whatever reason: different compilers, different configuration options, different architectures), there is only one single place to change.

Answer (score 7):

The code says this:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_HAS_DMA
#define __async_inline
#else
#define __async_inline __always_inline
#endif
```

It is self-explained. `__async_inline` will be replaced by `inline` if `CONFIG_HAS_DMA` is not defined.

Comment: but there is no such condition in my case

Comment: @Chinna where did you find this define ? http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.6.32;i=__async_inline